# Dark energy and matter in the Star Trek Universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-eu

Considering that it is currently one of the biggest topics in astrophysics at the moment, I was wondering whether anything in the *Star Trek* universe had anything to say on this matter (pun intended).  **Are there any references to Dark Energy and/or Dark Matter in the Star Trek Universe (2009 reboot universe included)** and, if so, **are there conjectures made about the nature of either?**  Canon sources are preferred, but non-canon are also accepted.

Comment: There's plenty in the EU books. Is it just the TV/Film canon you're interested in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in the reboot, but there are references to [dark matter](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Dark_matter) in the various series:

- High densities of dark matter can be very hazardous, as the Enterprise-D discovered in the [Mars Oscura](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Mar_Oscura_Nebula) dark matter nebula.
- Archer and T'Pol discovered they could illuminate a [dark matter nebula](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Dark_matter_nebula) using [metreon particles](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Metreon).
- Neelix told Kim and Paris of a time when he lost a nacelle due to the pressure built up by dark matter bow waves while traversing a dark matter nebula.
- [Graviton ellipses](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Graviton_ellipse) are attracted to dark matter, such as [dark matter asteroids](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Dark_matter_asteroid).
- [Dark matter lifeforms](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Dark_matter_lifeform) exist.

There is no mention of dark energy AFAICT.

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_matter_proto-comet

Answer (score 3):

Another answer here gives a thorough listing of references to **dark matter** in *Star Trek*, and is correct that no apparent references are made to **dark energy** in the television episodes or films.

There is a reference to dark energy, nevertheless, in ***[The Physics of Star Trek](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Physics_of_Star_Trek)*** by Lawrence M. Krauss, a theoretical physicist at Arizona State University. (The book's foreward was written by Professor Stephen Hawking.)

[image]

Krauss writes:

> We currently have no idea whatsoever why this **dark energy** is out there, or what its origin is...there is no way it could be harnessed to do any useful work like transporting spacecraft around.
>
> However, ignore for the moment the potential obstacles...

He then goes on to explain how one *might* use dark energy to "create and sustain the exotic matter and energy" required for propulsion in the *Star Trek* universe.

Answer (score 1):

No. Plain simple... No. There's no reference of Dark Energy and Dark Matter in Star Trek reboot (movie or comic).

Comment: *Citation needed*

Comment: @DVK The reboot canon is new, so it's not a big deal to find any reference, but how can I give citation in this NOT situation?

Answer (score 0):

Star Trek writers were able to see the folly which is "Dark Matter" etc.  This "missing" dark matter is nonsense.  The "missing" energy/matter/etc. are the exotic Black Holes whose numbers (i.e.count/survey/understanding) is astounding.  The "missing" dark matter is contained within the Dark Stars that are kinda hard to see, but common.  Roddenberry said as much before he keeled.

Comment: Do you have a reference for Roddenberry's feelings on Dark Matter? If you do, re-framing this question in terms of *his* feelings would improve it. As it stands it reads rather like a rant wrapped around a nugget of good answer